# Iterate json with multiple values per key for matching pattern: Set dataframe column value depending on value of other column (Faster Python Solution)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is the Problem statement.

**Inputs: -**

1. csv containing Time when a particular URL is hit.
2. json containing multiple url_categories with the matching url patters for each url_categories.

**Required Output: -**
csv, containing Time, url, and url_category. Where url_category is decided based on URL of input csv and url_patterns mentioned per url_category. If the URL doesn't match any of the patterns then category should be marked as 'Other'.

**Objective: -**
Python code should create the required output is a FAST way.

Input csv (simplified) which contains the time when a particular URL is hit, like below.

```
TIME,URL
11:51,/url3a/partC 
12:51,/url6/partA
13:51,/url7/partA/partA/partB
14:51,/url5/partA/partB/part1
15:51,/url3b/partA
16:51,/url8/partA/partB
17:51,/url2a/
18:51,/url5/partA/partB
19:51,/url1/part1/part2
20:51,/url4b/partA
21:51,/url9/partA/partA/partB
22:51,/url2/partA/partB
23:51,/url1a/partD
00:51,/url3/partA/partB
01:51,/url9/partA/partA/partB
02:51,/url4a/
03:51,/url5b/partA/partE
04:51,/url7/partA/partA/partB
05:51,/url1b/part1
```

Input json (simplified) describing URL categories with URL patterns, like below.

```
{
    "category1": [ "/url1/part1/part2", "/url1a/", "/url1b/part1" ],
    "category2": [ "/url2/partA/partB", "/url2a/", "/url2b/partA" ],
    "category3": [ "/url3/partA/partB", "/url3a/", "/url3b/partA" ],
    "category4": [ "/url4/partA/partB", "/url4a/", "/url4b/partA" ],
    "category5": [ "/url5/partA/partB", "/url5a/", "/url5b/partA" ],
}
```

I have a python code which achieves but it is very slow as I'm iterating through each dataframe row and each key & values in the json. **Need a solution which in which the code executes much faster**, as my input csv has many rows and input json also has many url categories and many url patterns associated with each url category.

```
json1 = '{"category1": ["/url1/part1/part2", "/url1a/", "/url1b/part1"], "category2": ["/url2/partA/partB", "/url2a/", "/url2b/partA"], "category3": ["/url3/partA/partB", "/url3a/", "/url3b/partA"], "category4": ["/url4/partA/partB", "/url4a/", "/url4b/partA"], "category5": ["/url5/partA/partB", "/url5a/", "/url5b/partA"]}'
print(json1)
json2 = json.loads(json1)
print(f"---json2: {json2}; \ntype(json2): {type(json2)}")

df = pd.read_csv(in_csv_path)
print(df)

for i in range(len(df)) :
    for key in json2:
        for url_pattern in json2[key]:
            if str(df.loc[i, "URL"]).find(str(url_pattern)) != -1:
                df.loc[i, "CATEGORY"] = key

df.fillna('Other', inplace=True)
print(df)

df.to_csv(out_csv, index=False)
```

Below is the output csv.

```
TIME,URL,CATEGORY
11:51,/url3a/partC ,category3
12:51,/url6/partA,Other
13:51,/url7/partA/partA/partB,Other
14:51,/url5/partA/partB,category5
15:51,/url3b/partA,category3
16:51,/url8/partA/partB,Other
17:51,/url2a/,category2
18:51,/url5/partA/partB,category5
19:51,/url1/part1/part2,category1
20:51,/url4b/partA,category4
21:51,/url9/partA/partA/partB,Other
22:51,/url2/partA/partB,category2
23:51,/url1a/,category1
00:51,/url3/partA/partB,category3
01:51,/url9/partA/partA/partB,Other
02:51,/url4a/,category4
03:51,/url5b/partA,category5
04:51,/url7/partA/partA/partB,Other
05:51,/url1b/part1,category1
```

Comment: How big is your dataset? Maybe `multiprocessing` will help.

Comment: I'm not looking for multiprocessing here. Is there any other way of doing it faster (e.g. lambda or anything like that?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following dataframe and json string:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"TIME": "11:51", "URL": "/url3a/partC"},
        {"TIME": "12:51", "URL": "/url6/partA"},
        {"TIME": "13:51", "URL": "/url7/partA/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "14:51", "URL": "/url5/partA/partB/part1"},
        {"TIME": "15:51", "URL": "/url3b/partA"},
        {"TIME": "16:51", "URL": "/url8/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "17:51", "URL": "/url2a/"},
        {"TIME": "18:51", "URL": "/url5/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "19:51", "URL": "/url1/part1/part2"},
        {"TIME": "20:51", "URL": "/url4b/partA"},
        {"TIME": "21:51", "URL": "/url9/partA/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "22:51", "URL": "/url2/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "23:51", "URL": "/url1a/partD"},
        {"TIME": "00:51", "URL": "/url3/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "01:51", "URL": "/url9/partA/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "02:51", "URL": "/url4a/"},
        {"TIME": "03:51", "URL": "/url5b/partA/partE"},
        {"TIME": "04:51", "URL": "/url7/partA/partA/partB"},
        {"TIME": "05:51", "URL": "/url1b/part1"},
    ]
)

categories = json.loads(
    '{"category1": ["/url1/part1/part2", "/url1a/", "/url1b/part1"], "category2": ["/url2/partA/partB", "/url2a/", "/url2b/partA"], "category3": ["/url3/partA/partB", "/url3a/", "/url3b/partA"], "category4": ["/url4/partA/partB", "/url4a/", "/url4b/partA"], "category5": ["/url5/partA/partB", "/url5a/", "/url5b/partA"]}'
)
```

Here is a more idiomatic way to do it:

```py
# Rework categories
categories = {
    url.split("/")[1]: cat for cat, urls in categories.items() for url in urls
}

# Process urls
df["Category"] = df["URL"].apply(lambda x: categories.get(x.split("/")[1], "Other"))
```

So that:

```py
print(df)
# Output
     TIME                      URL   Category
0   11:51             /url3a/partC  category3
1   12:51              /url6/partA      Other
2   13:51  /url7/partA/partA/partB      Other
3   14:51  /url5/partA/partB/part1  category5
4   15:51             /url3b/partA  category3
5   16:51        /url8/partA/partB      Other
6   17:51                  /url2a/  category2
7   18:51        /url5/partA/partB  category5
8   19:51        /url1/part1/part2  category1
9   20:51             /url4b/partA  category4
10  21:51  /url9/partA/partA/partB      Other
11  22:51        /url2/partA/partB  category2
12  23:51             /url1a/partD  category1
13  00:51        /url3/partA/partB  category3
14  01:51  /url9/partA/partA/partB      Other
15  02:51                  /url4a/  category4
16  03:51       /url5b/partA/partE  category5
17  04:51  /url7/partA/partA/partB      Other
18  05:51             /url1b/part1  category1
```

Comment: Thanks, It partially solves the problem. In final output the Category and url should be separate columns. Hence need to again split this output and create new column.

Comment: Right, see my updated answer. Cheers.